# Соединение 2х устройств в одной сети WiFi

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d, wifi, tcp

Здравстуйте!
Есть tcplistener на компьютере, и tcpclient на android смартфоне. Оба устройства подключены к 1 сети wifi (к компьютеру кабель от роутера, а телефон с раздачи). Какой адрес надо вводить на клиенте (телефоне) чтобы подключиться к компьютеру?

Пробовал ввести ipv4 из ipconfig'а компьютера, но никакой реакции нет. 
Через localhost все подключается...
Спасибо!

UPD: на клиенте исключение при подключении: The requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: 1) Смотрите на IP компьютера через ipconfig или админку роутера. 2) Открываете нужный вам порт в брандмауэре 3) Пробуете подключиться со смартфона, зная IP/порт компьютера.

Comment: @tym32167, 1. я же написал что смотрел через ipconfig, там ipv4 192.168.0.100. 2. брандмауэр выключен. 3. порт прописал 8888 и на сервере и на клиенте. Выдает ошибку на клиенте, The requested address is not valid in its context.

Comment: Очевидно, что раз связи нет - что то делаете не так. Попробуйте отправить ping со смартфона на PC (я это делал какой то отдельной прогой для андроида), поглядите настройки роутера (там должен быть список клиентов с IP адресами)

Comment: @tym32167 в списке, как и должно быть, 1 устройства (телефон). У телефона ip 192.168.0.101 (смотрел через настройки телефона, так как в списке у роутера показываются mac адреса). Попробовал пинговать с телефона на комп, прописал ipv4 компьютера (192.168.0.100), не пингуется, timed out :( не понимаю, что я делаю не так... А ничего что брандмауэр выключен?

Comment: С компьютера на телефон пингуется нормально.

Comment: @tym32167дело судя по всему в компьютере... Подключил к сети wifi другой телефон, и пингую с 1го телефона на другой, все пингуется, а на компьютер никак.

Comment: В списке на роутере должно быть 2 клиента - телефон и компьютер. И у каждого должен быть назначен IP адрес

Comment: @tym32167, да, действительно, есть 2 клиента (dhcp клиенты). И вот еще, оказывается брандмауэр был выключен не во всех сетях, в общем, выключил везде. Теперь все пингуется, и на компьютер, и на телефон. Но ошибка все еще осталась у клиента (исключение  The requested address is not valid in its context).

Comment: Если проблем с подключением больше нет, значит проблема где то в коде. Гуглите свою проблему, выкладывайте код, экспериментируйте. Я вот за 3 секунды [чтото нагуглил](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889972/the-requested-address-is-not-valid-in-its-context-when-i-try-to-listen-a-port)

Comment: @tym32167да, вы правы, проблема оказалась в коде! Я конструктору tcpclient'а передавал экземпляр IPEndPoint'а, а ему в конструктор передавал спарсенный ip. Было: client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.100")), 8888); Переделал:   client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.100", 8888); И заработало... Насколько я понял, тут ipendpoint не нужен. Я гуглил ошибку, но ответа не нашел.

Comment: Ваш прежний код не компилируется (видимо скобки не так расставлены в коде). Но, в любом случае, хорошо, что проблема решилась.

Comment: @tym32167, ручками писал. Да, скобочка лишняя есть. А какая разница если прямо прописать IP или через IPEndPoint? Если я не буду использовать wifi и буду пытаться подключиться к другому компьютеру, то IPEndPoint нужен будет?

Comment: Не уверен, но думаю, что какая то разницв есть. Поглядите в документации, может там чего написано. И я не думаю, что это как то связано со способом подключения к роутеру - ибо наладить подключение - это проблема роутера, не клиента/сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в коде, я прямо прописал ip в конструкторе tcpclient'а и заработало. Раньше я в конструктор передавал экземпляр IPEndPoint'а, и уже в его конструкторе парсил IP... Не знаю в чем разница. но без IPEndPoint'а заработало.